# Visual Studio market place is down

Tags: visual-studio, azure, marketplace

Not sure I'm only having this my issue or everybody experiencing the same, I'm trying to access https://marketplace.visualstudio.com

But not able to access!

Is there any issue/outage on the site(Microsoft)?

[image]

Comment: I ran into the same problem about an hour ago.

Comment: How do you expect the answer to look that you'd mark as "accepted"?

Comment: @nvoigt something like "The issue has been resolved"

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off-topic, because it clearly won't be useful as a reference to anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is an outage. The South Central region is down currently.

[image]

You can check the [Azure Status page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) to monitor updates.

Comment: is there a way of directing my vscode to a marketplace somewhere else in the world?? I am located in the middle east and don't understand why I am affected by the outage in south central America... Anyway, if I understand correctly, the marketplace has more endpoints around the world, so I would like to force my vscode to connect one of those, if that's possible...

Comment: The service itself is down because it authenticates through AAD and there is some reliance on that data center. https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-south-central-u-s-datacenter-outage-takes-down-a-number-of-cloud-services/

Comment: Welcome to the cloud. As the many become dependent on the benefits offered by a few , when the one of the few fails, many are left without a leg to stand on.

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT may I know what are all other services that are affected by this? your link in the comment  doesn't include the marketplace !

Comment: Yep! You can check: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: Marketplace is back to normal now